# What set does this light grey 2x8 overhanging brick with a 10 on the side belong to?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

[image]

I just received a huge box of LEGO pieces. There are some unique pieces such as this one.  On the back of this piece is the number AM02232. What are my options of figuring out its set and finding instructions? I'm brand new to the LEGO world, but kiddo is a builder at heart.

Comment: Doesnt look like LEGO brand to me, but a clone brand. Does it have the words LEGO on the top?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.  My first thought was that it doesn't look like the way LEGO does panels these days, but maybe it was from an era of LEGO that I missed.   Looking through https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=10#T=P&P=1 -- all of the parts that mention 10 -- I'm convinced it is from somebody other than LEGO.  Sadly that means there no way to be sure where it came from since there isn't a good database for non-LEGO parts.  If you also got any instructions just look for the non-LEGO ones.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I didn't see lego printed anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Confirmed that this is not LEGO, but Mega Bloks.

http://gamearn.me/mega-bloks-tank/mega-bloks-tank-legends-battle/

Not sure if it is from this set specifically (looks like it might have some stickers to add the camouflage or yours comes from a similar set).